# JQuery $(this) with class name

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecWT5/

It's 3 different colored blocks.

I want to show the color of the block on the block.

The blocks all have a class name.

So If I get the color using the class name it shows the same color on all blocks

Is it possible to use something like $(this) block with a class name to get the color of this block.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

        <head>  
            <meta charset="UTF-8">  
            <!--jQuery-->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


            <style type="text/css">
                *{
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                }

                .wrap{
                    margin: 50px;
                }

                .my_Box{
                    color: white;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
                    float: left;
                }

                .at-blue-lighter{
                    background-color: #70afe4;
                }

                .at-blue-light{
                    background-color: #4597dc;
                }

                .at-blue{
                    background-color: #267ec8;
                }
            </style>



            <title>Title of the document</title>
        </head>

    <body>

        <div class="wrap">
                <div class="my_Box at-blue-lighter" ><span></span></div>
                <div class="my_Box at-blue-light" ><span></span></div>
                <div class="my_Box at-blue" ><span></span></div>
            </div>

        <script>

            $(function(){

                var color = $('.my_Box').css('backgroundColor'); 

                $('.my_Box span').html(color);
            })

        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the receiver function of the `.text()`,

```
$('.my_Box').text(function(){
  return $(this).css('backgroundColor'); 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ecWT5/2/)

Side Note: Using `.html()` seems irrelevant here, so instead use `.text()`

---

In your code,

```
$('.my_Box').css('backgroundColor')
```

You are invoking `.css()` over a `collection` of elements since it would return only the css property value of the first element in that collection.

```
 $('.my_Box span').html(color);
```

As a consequence of the first step, each elements with the selector `.my_Box span` got assigned with the same value.